# Video upload using node js

Tags: html, sql, angularjs, node.js

Which package can be used in node js for uploading video and save to DB

Comment: This might help: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_video_upload

Answer (score 2):

First of all ,it is not a good practice to save your videos to the database.You could save it somewhere in the file system of your server or on remote storage buckets such as aws  S3  and just store the uri of the video in your database .
For very small files which don't require much processing you can try Mongo GridFs http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/tutorials/gridfs/streaming/

Answer (score -2):

there are different ways to upload videos in node i sujest you to use multer to store the video in database. you can easily find the multer npm and it is also very easy to upload video via multer 
[multer npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) this is the link where you find a better discription about multer and how to use it.